# Compilation error on AIX 6.1 - Undefined symbol: .__gcc_qsub

Tags: c, aix

I am running AIX 6.1, and GCC 4.2 and when I try compile SQLite (I think version 3.7.5) using the following commands:

```
gcc -maix64 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -c -fPIC -DHAVE_USLEEP ./sqlite/sqlite3.c -o ./sqlite/sqlite3.o
gcc -maix64 -shared –L/usr/lib/threads -o ./sqlite/libsqlite3.so ./sqlite/sqlite3.o –ldl -lpthread
```

I get the following errors:

```
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .__gcc_qsub
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .__gcc_qmul
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .__gcc_qadd
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
```

Do you have any idea what this could be caused from?

Any help would be hugely appreciated ;-)

Update 1:

Here is the verbose output:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -maix64 -v -shared-libgcc -L/usr/lib/threads -o ./sqlite/libsqlite3.so ./sqlite/sqlite3.o -lpthread
Using built-in specs.
Target: powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0
Configured with: ../configure --with-as=/usr/bin/as --with-ld=/usr/bin/ld --enable-languages=c,c++,java --prefix=/opt/freeware --enable-threads --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --host=powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0 --target=powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0 --build=powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0 --disable-libjava-multilib
Thread model: aix
gcc version 4.2.0
 /opt/freeware/libexec/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0/4.2.0/collect2 -bpT:0x10000000 -bpD:0x20000000 -btextro -bnodelcsect -b64 -o ./sqlite/libsqlite3.so /lib/crt0_64.o -L/usr/lib/threads -L/opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0/4.2.0/ppc64 -L/opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0/4.2.0 -L/opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0/4.2.0/../../.. ./sqlite/sqlite3.o -lpthread -lgcc_s /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0/4.2.0/ppc64/libgcc.a -lc -lgcc_s /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0/4.2.0/ppc64/libgcc.a
collect2: library libgcc_s not found
```

Comment: It sounds like it's picking up the wrong version of `libgcc`, which is implicitly added to the linker invocation by the gcc driver.  Could you please repeat your second command, with `-v` appended to the command line, and post the output?  That will reveal the command line the driver is using to run the linker.

Comment: Hi there, is added the -static-libgcc to the line and now it moans about undefined symbol: .main any ideas? I will post the -v result just now...thnx :-)

Comment: I was being stupid, I forgot the -shared, not it seems better...thnx

Comment: Hey Zack,I have added the verbose output above for your interest....but the -static-libgcc seems to help

Comment: Is there a libgcc_s.somethingorother anywhere in `/opt/freeware/lib/gcc`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-lm` to the link command to include the math library.

If not, check this [page](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=HowToCompile) and search for 'AIX'.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the tip....I will try that out tomorrow for sure...any other ideas if that does not work?

Comment: Edited with another suggestion.  I don't actually think `-lm` will help you as those symbols are within `libgcc`, but it's worth a try.